# Move constructor cannot be defaulted

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move

I am new to c++11 and wrote the following class where I would like it to support `std::move`:

```
class X {
 public:
  X(int x) : x_(x) {}
  ~X() {
    printf("X(%d) has be released.\n", x_);
  }

  X(X&&) = default;
  X& operator = (X&&) = default;

  X(const X&) = delete;
  X& operator = (const X&) = delete;
 private:
  int x_;
};
```

However, when I compile it with option `-std=c++0x`, the compiler complains the following:

```
queue_test.cc:12: error: ‘X::X(X&&)’ cannot be defaulted
queue_test.cc:13: error: ‘X& X::operator=(X&&)’ cannot be defaulted
```

My questions are:

1. Did I do something wrong which disallows class `X` to have a default move constructor?
2. In case there exists a class that we really can't default its move constructor, can I know how should I develop its move constructor?

Thank you,

Comment: -std=C++11, thats all

Comment: This is a bug in your - I assume old - compiler. [G++ even as old as 4.6.4 compiles the program without complaint](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c22306a9f7184539). Trying to learn C++11 with a compiler so old that it uses `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11` will probably be very challenging. Try to update to a recent compiler release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GCC's C++0x page:

> GCC's C++11 mode implements much of the C++11 standard produced by the
>   ISO C++ committee. The standard is available from various national
>   standards bodies; working papers from before the release of the
>   standard are available on the ISO C++ committee's web site at
>   http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/. Since this standard has only
>   recently been completed, the feature set provided by the experimental
>   **C++11 mode may vary greatly from one GCC version to another. No
>   attempts will be made to preserve backward compatibility with C++11
>   features whose semantics have changed during the course of C++11
>   standardization.**

The `std=c++11` flag was also introduced in GCC 4.7. From `man gcc` (I did not find it in `info gcc`):

```
c++11
c++0x
               The 2011 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.  Support for C++11
               is still experimental, and may change in incompatible ways in
               future releases. The name c++0x is deprecated.
```

I take this to mean in the latest compiler version, the flags are identical, but you should prefer `c++11` instead to avoid potential bugs.

From the `info gcc` command:

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is
>   '-std=gnu++98'.

This means `c++98` with extensions.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, the error was caused by incorrect compiler option.  Option `-std=c++11` should be used.  (note that it is lower case instead of upper case, otherwise the compiler will complain the following):

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=C++11’
```

Comment: See `info gcc` for more information next time. It gives a pretty thorough breakdown on the difference between the options. While I understand that it is confusing with compiler releases and how it affects the flags, a combination of looking at the gcc C++11 version support, `info gcc` and `man gcc` is all you need really.

Answer (score 1):

This code is compiled by GCC 4,8,1

Also the C++ Standard has the following example

```
struct trivial {
trivial() = default;
trivial(const trivial&) = default;
trivial(trivial&&) = default;
trivial& operator=(const trivial&) = default;
trivial& operator=(trivial&&) = default;
~trivial() = default;
};
```

I have not found the place in the standard where there would be said that move constructor may not be defaulted.

Comment: @keelar I use www.ideone.com where all options of the compiler that to compile code as C++ 11 are already set.

Comment: @keeler g++ should compile in gnu++98 mode by default.